# How to plot Venn diagram in python for two sets when one set is a subset of another?

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-venn

I use the following code to plot Venn diagrams. The problem is when one set is a subset of the other the code doesn't work (see the figure). How can I change the following code to make it work when one set is a subset of another? In this case, I expect the red circle to be inside the green circle (the color then probably should be the same as the color of the overlapped area instead of red).

```
sets = Counter()
sets['01'] = 10
sets['11'] = 5
sets['10']  = 5
setLabels = ['Set 1', 'set 2']

plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
v = venn2(subsets = sets, set_labels = setLabels, ax = ax)

h, l = [],[]
for i in sets:
    # remove label by setting them to empty string:
    v.get_label_by_id(i).set_text("")
    # append patch to handles list
    h.append(v.get_patch_by_id(i))
    # append count to labels list
    l.append(sets[i])

#create legend from handles and labels    
ax.legend(handles=h, labels=l, title="Numbers")

plt.title("venn_test")
plt.savefig("test_venn.png")
pdb.set_trace()
```

[image]

Comment: Try `sets['10'] = 0` instead, to make the red part (set 1 without set 2) empty.

Comment: Thanks! It kinda works, the only problem is that the legend shows the number of members for the red circle as zero.

Comment: You're welcome. You could slice the handles and labels in the legend call to suppress the empty set part: `ax.legend(handles=h[0:2], labels=l[0:2], title="Numbers")`

Comment: That works fine, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. I'll put this below as an answer for future reference then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `sets['10'] = 0`, to make the red part (set 1 without set 2) empty. To prevent that empty set from showing up in the legend, slice the handles and labels in the legend call accordingly: `ax.legend(handles=h[0:2], labels=l[0:2], title="Numbers")`

So change the code to this:

```
sets = Counter()
sets['01'] = 10
sets['11'] = 5
sets['10'] = 0  # set 1 without set 2 is empty
setLabels = ['Set 1', 'set 2']

plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
v = venn2(subsets = sets, set_labels = setLabels, ax = ax)

h, l = [],[]
for i in sets:
    # remove label by setting them to empty string:
    v.get_label_by_id(i).set_text("")
    # append patch to handles list
    h.append(v.get_patch_by_id(i))
    # append count to labels list
    l.append(sets[i])

#create legend from handles and labels, without the empty part    
ax.legend(handles=h[0:2], labels=l[0:2], title="Numbers")

plt.title("venn_test")
plt.savefig("test_venn.png")
pdb.set_trace()
```